# Line Chart in excel with date times

Tags: excel, date, linechart

I'm trying to create a line chart in excel where the x axis is date time.

ie, the format is

[image: Format]

But when I highlight the columns and click the line chart icon I get

[image: Problem]

Excel seems to insist on using only one of the dates and always puts the data series in the title.

This seems very strange to me.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It works so easy for this guy 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c-maLQM66bQ

Comment: hmm I probably should have posted on Super user now that you mention it. I found this question posted there. http://superuser.com/questions/541868/in-excel-how-do-i-plot-date-and-time-with-an-occurance
It seems like there is a work around but its not the greatest solution.

Comment: @pnuts I'm using 2013

Comment: The First Image appears when I highlight the dates column, right click it and select Format Cells ...

Comment: I figured it out, excel was formatting my second column of numbers as text. So the graph was not generating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, excel was formatting my second column of numbers as text. So the graph was not generating.

I didn't notice it at first, but the column indentation indicates that those numbers are actually text fields.

Answer (score 0):

You should mark the complete range A and B and then press the button for adding a line chart.

Comment: yea, it doesn't show in the image but I did that, excel kept insisting on changing the highlighting. probably due to the numbers being formatted a strings. note the indentation